# javascript library to load external csv file

Tags: javascript, html, css, csv

I'm working on visualizing flight parameters using web interface in html, css and javascipt.  I wonder what's the best free suitable javascript library to load data from the csv file generated by FDR(flight data recorder) and plot charts?

Comment: no is duplicated, my issue is totally different and i want serious answer not mentionning question as dupicated without understanding the question!

Comment: i have csv file containing flight data (12 parameters * 16 000 rows), i want to connect my web interface to it and load data and plot for example temerature before turbine = f(regime)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will help you (CSV to JSON): http://papaparse.com/